# How we can develop MS Office Word add-in using Meteor

Tags: meteor, ms-word, office365, office-js

I need to develop a MS Office Word add-in using the Word JavaScript API. My site is developed in Meteor so I want use the same resources for my Word add-in with a different layout. I tried to put my site URL in the add-in's SourceLocation element in addinManifest.xml but it displayed a blank page in the Word task pane.

Please advise: how can I use Meteor to develop a Word add-in?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend you to create a basic Word add-in first (have a look at the samples on Github. This should get you started on Word Add-ins in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Meteor to develop your add-in for Word. One reason why pointing the manifest directly to your existing site won't work is that you need to [reference Office.js and subscribe to the initialize event](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office).

Include on your page:

```html
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js"></script>
```

And in your code, call:

```js
Office.initialize = function () { };
```

-Michael, PM for Office add-ins

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michael,

Comment: I have tried with new Meteor application, Word pane display Application page correctly but when i added flow router and define the routing for Home page. It throw some exceptions.
Can you please guide me where i need to add define the 'Office.initialize' method.
Thanks.

Comment: Define Office.initialize directly after your page is finished loading.

Comment: Thanks Michael, now i am developing the add-in using HTML,CSS and javascript as i need to finish it soon.

I have placed my webAdd-in files on server and provided the URL in Manifest file.
On home page user need to login first and after login user can visit the add-in pages.I have below queies, please guide me:

1) How i can store the user credentials If user checked on store credentials checkbox for later login,system should not ask for login.

2) How should I store a token generated by a RESTful API after login to send the other request with Token and userId?.

Thanks